# Structure navigation between two screens without losing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql, vue.js

I have a difficult to structure navigation between two screens without losing data

For example, i have a Screen called Person with any properties, and a second object called Functions, Person has multiple functions, and functions has other items inside their.

Example:

```
{
   "Person":{
      "Functions":[
         {
            "name":"test A",
            "subItems":[
               {
                  "test":"A"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

When I go to add a function, my person screen lose the data because i navigate to other URL, how to save the data without save in local/session storage, using database like as a temporary model, and identify when delete it?

Comment: You would have to convert data to shareable format and return the data generated on the server in the first response and send it via post or get to second page and parse it again.